# Connecting several threaded plumbing components together

Tags: plumbing, pipe, brass-fitting

I have a string of brass components I need to connect together.

They all have corresponding Male/Female threads, so they all will go together, but is this a good idea?

It occurs to me that it will be difficult/impossible to tighten any of the fittings later without taking the whole lot to pieces?

Is there a 'typical' solution to this?

[image]

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/221755/18078

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually one does it right the first time, so there is no need to retighten the whole assembly. Since it is metal, you can use hemp and paste. Hemp swells on contact with water, so it forgives small flaws and tightens well.

To facilitate an eventual future removal, you could put an pipe union fitting on each end of the assembly.

[image: pipe union fitting]

Comment: Always best to get it right first time! I looked at the unions but for 1 1/4" they are about €40, which would make it cheaper put some copper in the middle and use some compression fittings.

Answer (score 0):

So you put a joint or 2 in place so that it can come apart.

Similar to:

[image]

Form: https://www.hornbach.ch/fr/p/raccord-visse-a-joint-conique-en-fonte-malleable-georg-fischer-gf-n340-3-8-fi/10555916/